# Figure out the least amount of duplicate data to fill a quota

Tags: code-golf, array

You are given 100 arrays/sets of 5-8 numbers between 1-20. If you combine all the arrays you will always get at least one of each number (1-20), so don't worry about an "unsolvable" case. The goal is to find the combination of arrays that minimizes duplicate numbers while still getting one of each number from 1-20.

Here's an example.

```
[1,5,16,12,9,3,7]
[10,13,6,5,7]
[2,17,8,18,12]
[4,3,11,14,7]
[15,19,20,1]
```

The above sets fill all the numbers from 1-20. The only slight problem is that it has duplicates. There are multiple 5s, 7s, and 1s. Duplicates are fine. In 100 arrays you most likely aren't going to find a perfect match with no duplicates, but the goal is to minimize the number of duplicates you get. The code should work with any random 100 arrays. Good luck! Hopefully, you might find a dynamic, smart technique, but brute force is perfectly fine.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Right now, this challenge seems a bit under-specified. Also, I'd recommend to remove the constraint of 100 arrays which makes it unpractical for brute force. You're likely to get answers that only work in theory but are not going to produce any output before the heat death of the universe. How about just taking a list of any number of sets?

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf again.  I think you need at least to specify what 'minimize the number of duplicates' means: does it mean minimizing the number of distinct values that occur more-than-once (so 1,1,5,5,7,7 counts as 3), or does it mean minimizing the total number of occurring-more-than-once elements (so 1,1,5,5,7,7 counts as 6)?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen It means that if you have 2 arrays with completely unique numbers, except 1 number, which is shared between two arrays, that would be a "duplicate". You're trying to minimise those.

Comment: @RevelCarlbergWest - I think the core idea of the challenge is interesting, but I still think you need to specify how you quantify (in order to minimize) 'duplicates' better.  If you do this, and edit it into the question, then it's more likely to be re-opened.  It's a good idea to think-up some test cases to make clear what you mean.  An example: [[1..5,20],[6..10,20],[11..15,20],[16..20],[1,6..20]] - in this case, choosing the first 4 sets gives the number 20 duplicated 4 times, whereas choosing the first and last sets gives the numbers 1 and 20 each duplicated twice.  Which is 'minimized'?